# mutate new continuous variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset over time of patients with declining concentration of biomarker x. I am trying to find the first occasion that the percentage of peak x falls below 25%, or where the absolute value of x falls below 34 for men or 16 for women. I have done the % part:

```
df25 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(x_25 = which(x_frac <=25)[1])
```

but I was wondering how you could combine the absolute values into this? I’ve tried the following, but it doesn’t work:

```
df25a <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(x_25a = ifelse(x_frac>=25 & x<=34, day, NA))
```

I would be very grateful for your expertise, bw Annemarie

```
id  day x   x_frac  sex    "hoped for x_25"
1   0   1935    100 0                 2
1   1   1039    54  0                 2
1   2   308     16  0                 2
1   3   112     6   0                 2  
2   0   31      100 1                 1  
2   1   11      35  1                 1   
3   0   204     100 0                 NA   
3   1   178     87  0                 NA
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: @akrun I've added a "hoped for" output to my question thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be lower than 25, `x_frac<=25` ?

Comment: @timfaber. I am looking for the first time the concentration falls to <25%, or the time the concentration falls below 34 (or 16 for gender==1), even if x_frac remains >25% . It would be more elegant to miss out that step... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to make sense, maybe something like this? (this does not match your hoped col but matches your description, I think)

```
df25a <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(x_25a = ifelse(sex==0,ifelse(x_frac<=25 | x<=34, day, NA),
                               ifelse(x_frac<=25 | x<=16, day, NA)))
```

And the summary version:

```
df25 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(x_25 = ifelse(sex[1]==0,which(x_frac <=25 | x<=34)[1],
                                                                  which(x_frac <=25 | x<=16)[1]))
```

Comment: Yes, that's brilliant thank you. Is it possible to select out the first non-NA value for x_25a for each patient? I've tried the following, but if the first value is NA, then it makes the whole patient NA. Thanks         `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(x_25b = first(x_25a))`

Comment: I added a summary version which produces the index (thereby discarding NAs). Is that useful for you?